# Energy transfer from P680 to oxygen-evolving complex

Tags: biochemistry, photosynthesis, thermodynamics

This topic is confusing me.

As I understand it, in the PS2, photons are used to split water into molecular oxygen + protons and electrons in the oxygen-evolving complex. To do this, a photon is used to excite an electron in the P<sub>680</sub>, this electron is then released to go through the electron transport chain and somehow the oxygen-evolving complex gets energy from it to make water endure a "photochemical reaction" as described in my biology book.

But how the electron can transfer its energy to the oxygen-evolving complex if it went directly to the electron transport chain? how the energy produced in the P<sub>680</sub> transported to the Oxygen-evolving complex?

I would appreciate simple terms as I'm still a college student.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to think the other way around: don't pay attention to *where* the electron from P<sub>680</sub> is going.

Instead of that, pay attention to this fact: after PSII absorbs a photon and triggers the loss of an electron from a P<sub>680</sub> chlorophyll *a* molecule, this P<sub>680</sub> has now an electron deficit. That is, this P<sub>680</sub> **has lost** one electron.

This P<sub>680</sub> without one electron is now called P<sub>680</sub><sup>+</sup>. And here comes the important information, which answers your question: According to Lodish (2002),

> P<sub>680</sub><sup>+</sup>, the photochemically oxidized reaction-center chlorophyll of PSII, is the **strongest biological oxidant known**. (emphasis mine)

And that explains what (thermodynamically) drives O<sub>2</sub>-evolving complex (still according to Lodish, 2002):

> The reduction potential of P<sub>680</sub><sup>+</sup> is **more positive than that of water**, and thus it can oxidize water to give O<sub>2</sub> and H<sup>+</sup> ions. (emphasis mine)

I hope those terms are simple enough for you. Finally, for better understanding all this, have a look at the concept of [reduction potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_potential) (which, as a college student, I believe you have to study).

---

Source:

- [Lodish, H. (2002). Molecular cell biology. 4th ed. New York, N.Y.: Freeman](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21484/).